# Upload a large file to server using multipart request and read the progress using rest kit

Tags: ios, file-upload, nsurlconnection, restkit, afnetworking

I have a requirement in my app where i need to upload a files with large data to server and track the upload progress.

Earlier my app used to just upload data to a server which I have done sending multipart request to server using rest kit (My app uses rest kit). Now I have a requirement to indicate the user about the progress.

I am trying to learn if rest kit has a provisioning to do so where it responds the view controller with the progress.

I came across few blogs which says AFNetwork supports to do so.As rest kit makes use of AFNetworking I suspect there should be a provision to accomplish my task. Unfortunately could not find enough pointers and hence posting it here.

I guess there should be someone who came across such requirements and waiting to receive your pointers.

Any pointers and if possible code snippets is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and you use the AFNetworking progress callbacks.

You can't directly use the `RKObjectManager`, you need to create the appropriate `NSOperation` to action your request (probably with `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:method:path:parameters:`). Once you have that you can do:

```
[operation.HTTPRequestOperation setUploadProgressBlock:...];
```